# "xmodmap -pke" shows more than 6 columns

Tags: x11, keyboard-layout, xmodmap

[Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap#Keymap_table) and other sites only explain the first 6 columns in "xmodmap -pke":

> Print the current keymap table formatted into expressions:
>
> ```
> $ xmodmap -pke
> [...]
> keycode  57 = n N
> [...]
> ```
>
> Each keycode is followed by the keysym it is mapped to. The above example indicates that the keycode 57 is mapped to the lowercase n, while the uppercase N is mapped to keycode 57 plus Shift.
>
> Each keysym column in the table corresponds to a particular combination of modifier keys:
>
> ```
> Key
> Shift+Key
> mode_switch+Key
> mode_switch+Shift+Key
> AltGr+Key
> AltGr+Shift+Key
> ```
>
> Not all keysyms have to be set, but to assign only a latter keysym, use the NoSymbol value.
>   However, running "xmodmap -pke" gives me about 10 columns for some keys:

```
[hax@localhost ~]$ xmodmap -pke
keycode   8 =
keycode   9 = Escape NoSymbol Escape
keycode  10 = 1 exclam 1 exclam onesuperior exclamdown
keycode  11 = 2 at 2 at twosuperior oneeighth
keycode  12 = 3 numbersign 3 numerosign threesuperior sterling
keycode  13 = 4 dollar 4 dollar onequarter dollar EuroSign EuroSign
keycode  14 = 5 percent 5 percent onehalf threeeighths
keycode  15 = 6 asciicircum 6 EuroSign threequarters fiveeighths
keycode  16 = 7 ampersand 7 section lowleftcorner upleftcorner
keycode  17 = 8 asterisk 8 asterisk leftt topt
keycode  18 = 9 parenleft 9 parenleft rightt bott bracketleft U2329
keycode  19 = 0 parenright 0 parenright lowrightcorner uprightcorner bracketright U232A
keycode  20 = minus underscore minus endash horizlinescan5 vertbar U2011 U2011
keycode  21 = equal plus equal plus crossinglines dead_ogonek emdash dagger
keycode  22 = BackSpace BackSpace BackSpace BackSpace
keycode  23 = Tab ISO_Left_Tab Tab ISO_Left_Tab
keycode  24 = q Q Cyrillic_ya Cyrillic_YA at Greek_OMEGA U0463 U0462
keycode  25 = w W Cyrillic_ve Cyrillic_VE lstroke Lstroke
keycode  26 = e E Cyrillic_ie Cyrillic_IE EuroSign VoidSymbol Cyrillic_e Cyrillic_E
keycode  27 = r R Cyrillic_er Cyrillic_ER paragraph registered registered registered
keycode  28 = t T Cyrillic_te Cyrillic_TE tslash Tslash trademark trademark
keycode  29 = y Y Cyrillic_hardsign Cyrillic_HARDSIGN leftarrow yen U046B U046A
keycode  30 = u U Cyrillic_u Cyrillic_U udiaeresis Udiaeresis
keycode  31 = i I Cyrillic_i Cyrillic_I idotless Iabovedot U045D U040D
keycode  32 = o O Cyrillic_o Cyrillic_O odiaeresis Odiaeresis
keycode  33 = p P Cyrillic_pe Cyrillic_PE thorn THORN
keycode  34 = bracketleft braceleft Cyrillic_sha Cyrillic_SHA dead_diaeresis dead_abovering
keycode  35 = bracketright braceright Cyrillic_shcha Cyrillic_SHCHA dead_tilde dead_macron
keycode  36 = Return NoSymbol Return
keycode  37 = Control_L NoSymbol Control_L
keycode  38 = a A Cyrillic_a Cyrillic_A acircumflex Acircumflex
keycode  39 = s S Cyrillic_es Cyrillic_ES scedilla Scedilla copyright copyright
keycode  40 = d D Cyrillic_de Cyrillic_DE eth ETH
keycode  41 = f F Cyrillic_ef Cyrillic_EF dstroke ordfeminine
keycode  42 = g G Cyrillic_ghe Cyrillic_GHE gbreve Gbreve
keycode  43 = h H Cyrillic_ha Cyrillic_HA hstroke Hstroke
keycode  44 = j J Cyrillic_shorti Cyrillic_SHORTI dead_hook dead_horn U046D U046C
keycode  45 = k K Cyrillic_ka Cyrillic_KA kra ampersand
keycode  46 = l L Cyrillic_el Cyrillic_EL lstroke Lstroke
keycode  47 = semicolon colon semicolon colon dead_acute dead_doubleacute ellipsis ellipsis                                                                  
keycode  48 = apostrophe quotedbl apostrophe quotedbl dead_circumflex dead_caron rightsinglequotemark leftsinglequotemark                                    
keycode  49 = grave asciitilde Cyrillic_che Cyrillic_CHE notsign notsign                                                                                     
keycode  50 = Shift_L ISO_Next_Group Shift_L ISO_Next_Group                                                                                                  
keycode  51 = backslash bar Cyrillic_yu Cyrillic_YU dead_grave dead_breve                                                                                    
keycode  52 = z Z Cyrillic_ze Cyrillic_ZE guillemotleft less                                                                                                 
keycode  53 = x X Cyrillic_softsign U045D guillemotright greater Cyrillic_yeru Cyrillic_YERU                                                                 
keycode  54 = c C Cyrillic_tse Cyrillic_TSE ccedilla Ccedilla copyright copyright
keycode  55 = v V Cyrillic_zhe Cyrillic_ZHE leftdoublequotemark leftsinglequotemark
keycode  56 = b B Cyrillic_be Cyrillic_BE rightdoublequotemark rightsinglequotemark
keycode  57 = n N Cyrillic_en Cyrillic_EN n N
keycode  58 = m M Cyrillic_em Cyrillic_EM mu masculine
keycode  59 = comma less comma doublelowquotemark horizconnector multiply guillemotleft guillemotleft
keycode  60 = period greater period leftdoublequotemark periodcentered division guillemotright guillemotright
keycode  61 = slash question slash question dead_belowdot dead_abovedot U0300 U0301
keycode  62 = Shift_R ISO_Next_Group Shift_R ISO_Next_Group
keycode  63 = KP_Multiply KP_Multiply KP_Multiply KP_Multiply KP_Multiply KP_Multiply XF86ClearGrab KP_Multiply KP_Multiply XF86ClearGrab
keycode  64 = Alt_L ISO_Next_Group Alt_L ISO_Next_Group
keycode  65 = space NoSymbol space space nobreakspace nobreakspace
keycode  66 = Caps_Lock NoSymbol Caps_Lock
keycode  67 = F1 F1 F1 F1 F1 F1 XF86Switch_VT_1 F1 F1 XF86Switch_VT_1
keycode  68 = F2 F2 F2 F2 F2 F2 XF86Switch_VT_2 F2 F2 XF86Switch_VT_2
keycode  69 = F3 F3 F3 F3 F3 F3 XF86Switch_VT_3 F3 F3 XF86Switch_VT_3
keycode  70 = F4 F4 F4 F4 F4 F4 XF86Switch_VT_4 F4 F4 XF86Switch_VT_4
keycode  71 = F5 F5 F5 F5 F5 F5 XF86Switch_VT_5 F5 F5 XF86Switch_VT_5
keycode  72 = F6 F6 F6 F6 F6 F6 XF86Switch_VT_6 F6 F6 XF86Switch_VT_6
keycode  73 = F7 F7 F7 F7 F7 F7 XF86Switch_VT_7 F7 F7 XF86Switch_VT_7
keycode  74 = F8 F8 F8 F8 F8 F8 XF86Switch_VT_8 F8 F8 XF86Switch_VT_8
keycode  75 = F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 XF86Switch_VT_9 F9 F9 XF86Switch_VT_9
keycode  76 = F10 F10 F10 F10 F10 F10 XF86Switch_VT_10 F10 F10 XF86Switch_VT_10
keycode  77 = Num_Lock NoSymbol Num_Lock
keycode  78 = Scroll_Lock NoSymbol Scroll_Lock
keycode  79 = KP_Home KP_7 KP_Home KP_7
keycode  80 = KP_Up KP_8 KP_Up KP_8
keycode  81 = KP_Prior KP_9 KP_Prior KP_9
keycode  82 = KP_Subtract KP_Subtract KP_Subtract KP_Subtract KP_Subtract KP_Subtract XF86Prev_VMode KP_Subtract KP_Subtract XF86Prev_VMode
keycode  83 = KP_Left KP_4 KP_Left KP_4
keycode  84 = KP_Begin KP_5 KP_Begin KP_5
keycode  85 = KP_Right KP_6 KP_Right KP_6
keycode  86 = KP_Add KP_Add KP_Add KP_Add KP_Add KP_Add XF86Next_VMode KP_Add KP_Add XF86Next_VMode
keycode  87 = KP_End KP_1 KP_End KP_1
keycode  88 = KP_Down KP_2 KP_Down KP_2
keycode  89 = KP_Next KP_3 KP_Next KP_3
keycode  90 = KP_Insert KP_0 KP_Insert KP_0
keycode  91 = KP_Delete KP_Decimal KP_Delete KP_Separator
keycode  92 = ISO_Level3_Shift NoSymbol ISO_Level3_Shift
keycode  93 =
keycode  94 = Alt_L ISO_Next_Group Alt_L ISO_Next_Group
keycode  95 = F11 F11 F11 F11 F11 F11 XF86Switch_VT_11 F11 F11 XF86Switch_VT_11
keycode  96 = F12 F12 F12 F12 F12 F12 XF86Switch_VT_12 F12 F12 XF86Switch_VT_12
keycode  97 =
keycode  98 = Katakana NoSymbol Katakana
keycode  99 = Hiragana NoSymbol Hiragana
keycode 100 = Henkan_Mode NoSymbol Henkan_Mode
keycode 101 = Hiragana_Katakana NoSymbol Hiragana_Katakana
keycode 102 = Muhenkan NoSymbol Muhenkan
keycode 103 =
keycode 104 = KP_Enter NoSymbol KP_Enter
keycode 105 = Control_R NoSymbol Control_R
keycode 106 = KP_Divide KP_Divide KP_Divide KP_Divide KP_Divide KP_Divide XF86Ungrab KP_Divide KP_Divide XF86Ungrab
keycode 107 = Print Sys_Req Print Sys_Req
keycode 108 = space NoSymbol space
keycode 109 = Linefeed NoSymbol Linefeed
keycode 110 = Home NoSymbol Home
keycode 111 = Up NoSymbol Up
keycode 112 = Prior NoSymbol Prior
keycode 113 = Left NoSymbol Left
keycode 114 = Right NoSymbol Right
keycode 115 = End NoSymbol End
keycode 116 = Down NoSymbol Down
keycode 117 = Next NoSymbol Next
keycode 118 = Control_L NoSymbol Control_L
keycode 119 = Delete NoSymbol Delete
keycode 120 =
keycode 121 = XF86AudioMute NoSymbol XF86AudioMute
keycode 122 = XF86AudioLowerVolume NoSymbol XF86AudioLowerVolume
keycode 123 = XF86AudioRaiseVolume NoSymbol XF86AudioRaiseVolume
keycode 124 = XF86PowerOff NoSymbol XF86PowerOff
keycode 125 = KP_Equal NoSymbol KP_Equal
keycode 126 = plusminus NoSymbol plusminus
keycode 127 = Insert NoSymbol Insert
keycode 128 = XF86LaunchA NoSymbol XF86LaunchA
keycode 129 = KP_Decimal KP_Decimal KP_Decimal KP_Decimal
keycode 130 = Hangul NoSymbol Hangul
keycode 131 = Hangul_Hanja NoSymbol Hangul_Hanja
keycode 132 =
keycode 133 = Super_L NoSymbol Super_L
keycode 134 = Super_R NoSymbol Super_R
keycode 135 = ISO_Level3_Shift NoSymbol ISO_Level3_Shift
keycode 136 = Cancel NoSymbol Cancel
keycode 137 = Redo NoSymbol Redo
keycode 138 = SunProps NoSymbol SunProps
keycode 139 = Undo NoSymbol Undo
keycode 140 = SunFront NoSymbol SunFront
keycode 141 = XF86Copy NoSymbol XF86Copy
keycode 142 = XF86Open NoSymbol XF86Open
keycode 143 = XF86Paste NoSymbol XF86Paste
keycode 144 = Find NoSymbol Find
keycode 145 = XF86Cut NoSymbol XF86Cut
keycode 146 = Help NoSymbol Help
keycode 147 = XF86MenuKB NoSymbol XF86MenuKB
keycode 148 = XF86Calculator NoSymbol XF86Calculator
keycode 149 =
keycode 150 = XF86Sleep NoSymbol XF86Sleep
keycode 151 = XF86WakeUp NoSymbol XF86WakeUp
keycode 152 = XF86Explorer NoSymbol XF86Explorer
keycode 153 = XF86Send NoSymbol XF86Send
keycode 154 =
keycode 155 = XF86Xfer NoSymbol XF86Xfer
keycode 156 = XF86Launch1 NoSymbol XF86Launch1
keycode 157 = XF86Launch2 NoSymbol XF86Launch2
keycode 158 = XF86WWW NoSymbol XF86WWW
keycode 159 = XF86DOS NoSymbol XF86DOS
keycode 160 = XF86ScreenSaver NoSymbol XF86ScreenSaver
keycode 161 = XF86RotateWindows NoSymbol XF86RotateWindows
keycode 162 = XF86TaskPane NoSymbol XF86TaskPane
keycode 163 = XF86Mail NoSymbol XF86Mail
keycode 164 = XF86Favorites NoSymbol XF86Favorites
keycode 165 = XF86MyComputer NoSymbol XF86MyComputer
keycode 166 = XF86Back NoSymbol XF86Back
keycode 167 = XF86Forward NoSymbol XF86Forward
keycode 168 =
keycode 169 = XF86Eject NoSymbol XF86Eject
keycode 170 = XF86Eject XF86Eject XF86Eject XF86Eject
keycode 171 = XF86AudioNext NoSymbol XF86AudioNext
keycode 172 = XF86AudioPlay XF86AudioPause XF86AudioPlay XF86AudioPause
keycode 173 = XF86AudioPrev NoSymbol XF86AudioPrev
keycode 174 = XF86AudioStop XF86Eject XF86AudioStop XF86Eject
keycode 175 = XF86AudioRecord NoSymbol XF86AudioRecord
keycode 176 = XF86AudioRewind NoSymbol XF86AudioRewind
keycode 177 = XF86Phone NoSymbol XF86Phone
keycode 178 =
keycode 179 = XF86Tools NoSymbol XF86Tools
keycode 180 = XF86HomePage NoSymbol XF86HomePage
keycode 181 = XF86Reload NoSymbol XF86Reload
keycode 182 = XF86Close NoSymbol XF86Close
keycode 183 =
keycode 184 =
keycode 185 = XF86ScrollUp NoSymbol XF86ScrollUp
keycode 186 = XF86ScrollDown NoSymbol XF86ScrollDown
keycode 187 = parenleft NoSymbol parenleft
keycode 188 = parenright NoSymbol parenright
keycode 189 = XF86New NoSymbol XF86New
keycode 190 = Redo NoSymbol Redo
keycode 191 = XF86Tools NoSymbol XF86Tools
keycode 192 = XF86Launch5 NoSymbol XF86Launch5
keycode 193 = XF86Launch6 NoSymbol XF86Launch6
keycode 194 = XF86Launch7 NoSymbol XF86Launch7
keycode 195 = XF86Launch8 NoSymbol XF86Launch8
keycode 196 = XF86Launch9 NoSymbol XF86Launch9
keycode 197 =
keycode 198 = XF86AudioMicMute NoSymbol XF86AudioMicMute
keycode 199 = XF86TouchpadToggle NoSymbol XF86TouchpadToggle
keycode 200 = XF86TouchpadOn NoSymbol XF86TouchpadOn
keycode 201 = XF86TouchpadOff NoSymbol XF86TouchpadOff
keycode 202 =
keycode 203 = Mode_switch NoSymbol Mode_switch
keycode 204 = NoSymbol Alt_L NoSymbol Alt_L
keycode 205 = NoSymbol Meta_L NoSymbol Meta_L
keycode 206 = NoSymbol Super_L NoSymbol Super_L
keycode 207 = NoSymbol Hyper_L NoSymbol Hyper_L
keycode 208 = XF86AudioPlay NoSymbol XF86AudioPlay
keycode 209 = XF86AudioPause NoSymbol XF86AudioPause
keycode 210 = XF86Launch3 NoSymbol XF86Launch3
keycode 211 = XF86Launch4 NoSymbol XF86Launch4
keycode 212 = XF86LaunchB NoSymbol XF86LaunchB
keycode 213 = XF86Suspend NoSymbol XF86Suspend
keycode 214 = XF86Close NoSymbol XF86Close
keycode 215 = XF86AudioPlay NoSymbol XF86AudioPlay
keycode 216 = XF86AudioForward NoSymbol XF86AudioForward
keycode 217 =
keycode 218 = Print NoSymbol Print
keycode 219 =
keycode 220 = XF86WebCam NoSymbol XF86WebCam
keycode 221 =
keycode 222 =
keycode 223 = XF86Mail NoSymbol XF86Mail
keycode 224 = XF86Messenger NoSymbol XF86Messenger
keycode 225 = XF86Search NoSymbol XF86Search
keycode 226 = XF86Go NoSymbol XF86Go
keycode 227 = XF86Finance NoSymbol XF86Finance
keycode 228 = XF86Game NoSymbol XF86Game
keycode 229 = XF86Shop NoSymbol XF86Shop
keycode 230 =
keycode 231 = Cancel NoSymbol Cancel
keycode 232 = XF86MonBrightnessDown NoSymbol XF86MonBrightnessDown
keycode 233 = XF86MonBrightnessUp NoSymbol XF86MonBrightnessUp
keycode 234 = XF86AudioMedia NoSymbol XF86AudioMedia
keycode 235 = XF86Display NoSymbol XF86Display
keycode 236 = XF86KbdLightOnOff NoSymbol XF86KbdLightOnOff
keycode 237 = XF86KbdBrightnessDown NoSymbol XF86KbdBrightnessDown
keycode 238 = XF86KbdBrightnessUp NoSymbol XF86KbdBrightnessUp
keycode 239 = XF86Send NoSymbol XF86Send
keycode 240 = XF86Reply NoSymbol XF86Reply
keycode 241 = XF86MailForward NoSymbol XF86MailForward
keycode 242 = XF86Save NoSymbol XF86Save
keycode 243 = XF86Documents NoSymbol XF86Documents
keycode 244 = XF86Battery NoSymbol XF86Battery
keycode 245 = XF86Bluetooth NoSymbol XF86Bluetooth
keycode 246 = XF86WLAN NoSymbol XF86WLAN
keycode 247 =
keycode 248 =
keycode 249 =
keycode 250 =
keycode 251 =
keycode 252 =
keycode 253 =
keycode 254 =
keycode 255 =
```

What do those columns mean?

I have Turkish layout that is similar to English, but with Alt Gr modifier for non-english characters (ü, ğ, etc.) and a second layout for Cyrillic.
I'm running Fedora 24 KDE.

Comment: [Please do not post pictures of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).

Comment: i have no idea what the columns mean because i can't even read the fuzzy squinty little text in your screenshot.  if you want people to help you then don't put obstacles in their way.  or, as Gilles said: [Please don't post pictures of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)

Comment: @cas I will change the picture into text, okay. But you know you could've clicked the picture to get the original size, right? The text is anything but fuzzy or squinty.

Comment: maybe that's true on your monitor.  it's not true on any higher-resolution /  higher-dpi monitor (like a 4K monitor, or my 1440p monitor).

Comment: @cas You're right, I didn't think of that. I imagine on mobile it must be pretty annoying to have to open the image in a new tab and zoom it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your configuration likely has *virtual modifiers* (a feature added about ten years ago, without completing the documentation).

They have no predefined meanings.  Quoting from *How to further enhance XKB configuration*:

> Any key type description can use both real and virtual modifiers. Since real modifiers always have standard names it is not necessary to explicitly declare them. Virtual modifiers can have ***arbitrary names*** and can be declared (prior using them) directly in key type definition:

Here are some places where it is discussed:

- [How to further enhance XKB configuration](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/input/XKB-Enhancing.html)
- [An Unreliable Guide to XKB Configuration: The Basics](http://www.charvolant.org/~doug/xkb/html/node3.html)
- [Some words about XKB internals.](http://pascal.tsu.ru/en/xkb/internals.html)

as well as manual pages

- [XkbVirtualModsToReal - Determines the mapping of virtual modifiers to core X protocol modifiers](http://linux.die.net/man/3/xkbvirtualmodstoreal)
- [XkbGetVirtualMods - Obtain a subset of the virtual modifier bindings (the vmods array) in a keyboard description](http://linux.die.net/man/3/xkbgetvirtualmods)
- [XkbSetServerInternalMods - Sets the modifiers that are consumed by the server before events are delivered to the client](http://linux.die.net/man/3/xkbsetserverinternalmods)

Comment: Thanks, great answer! I'll check it out. It seems how the keyboard works in Linux is quite complicated. One would assume it would be straighforward... one would assume.

Comment: Could you please provide a quick guide on how to get `xmodmap` working on any key? For example it works on the `c` key for me which uses 16 columns but it doesnit work for the `,` key which only uses 8 columns even if you assign more columns using `xmodmap`. The result is that when using `us(cz_sk_de)` keyboard layout I cannot assign other characters to AltGr+comma for example.